# "Take a degree" or "do a degree"

Tags: word-choice, collocation

In university I learned that we say *to do a degree in X* but I saw many other sources where it says *to take a degree in X*.

Which is correct? Is there a regional difference?

Comment: In the US, at least, you generally *get* a degree.

Comment: And in the US, before you actually *get* a degree, you are *working on* it, not *doing* it.

Comment: I am in the US.  My impression that "take a degree" is British terminology.  If so, it would have been good if those answers from 10 years ago also told us what location they are talking about.

Answer (score 8):

The OED’s definition 34a of *take* is:

> To receive, get (something given, bestowed, or administered); to have
>   conferred upon one (spec. a sacrament, office, order of merit, degree,
>   etc.)

That confirms my first thought that you can only *take a degree* once you have earned it. Before you reach that stage you have to *study for a degree* or, much less formally, *do a degree*. In British universities you can *read for a degree*, but that has a rather stiff sound to it these days.

Comment: But after you have accepted your degree then take is no longer relevant. You must have taken or even took a degree. Whilst studying is **take verb (ACT); to do or perform:
Shelley is taking (= studying) economics at university**. Also, the question is, I would suggest, incorrect. 
*In university I learned that we say I am **doing** a degree in X but I saw many other sources where it says taking a degree in X*. Unless gaining a degree has become instantaneous, not continuous.

Comment: Just to be clear: Barrie England's answer was posted in 2011. His last answer on EL&U was posted in 2014 and the last time he logged in was 8 months ago. It's unlikely that he will respond to any comment or observations.

Answer (score 6):

I would generally say, and usually hear, that a person is **pursuing** a degree in something.  Such as, "John is pursuing a double degree in business and marketing."

Answer (score 5):

Agreed:

You can pursue a degree in X.
You can get a degree in x. (Americans use this expression most.)
And you can work on/towards a degree in x.

North Americans would very much be at a loss hearing "do/take a degree".

Answer (score 1):

Both are fine, but in the States we usually say, "get a degree in" while in the process and "have a degree in" once it has been conferred.