# Did I "get" (or "take") my degree "from" (or "in") the University of Somewhere?

Tags: writing-style

I would like to know what is the preferred way to indicate that I took a degree in some subject while also naming the place where I obtained the degree from:

- I got my master's degree *from* the University of Somewhere;
- I got my master's degree *in* the University of Somewhere;
- I took my master's degree *in* the University of Somewhere.

I would say that "in" is more suitable to mention the particular subject (a degree in maths, for instance) than to indicate the place, but I still have doubts.

By the way, is it a "master's degree" or a "Master's degree"?

Comment: Whether you "got your degree from UoS" or "took your degree at UoS" depends on whether Somewhere is in North America or on the British Isles.

Comment: This is similar to http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46667/take-a-degree-or-do-a-degree. Not voting to close, because it includes the additional question about 'from' or 'in [the University of . . .]

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, you *take* courses, *get* or *receive* degrees.

Answer (score 12):

Firstly, a master's degree is not proper and therefore does not *require* capitalization, but personally I've seen several highly professional institutions spell it both ways.

Seeing as how all three of those sentences are grammatically sound, it's more a question of etiquette or regional custom. Like Peter Shor was saying, it's not wrong to say that you *took* your master's degree *in* somewhere but you may have to use caution repeating prepositions.

e.g. *I took my master's degree in astrophysics in the University of Somewhere*

Using *in* twice is potentially awkward in situations where you may need to elaborate on your area of study.

To answer your question, all of those examples are grammatically strong and should get the message across appropriately anywhere you go.

On an editorial note, however, there are some ways to bypass this dilemma by opting for more colorful words:

*I (**received, earned, attained**) a master's degree after (**studying in/at, attending, graduating from**) the University of Somewhere.*

Play it right and you'll sound like a Nobel Laureate, but all of your sentences will work well; none of them is really noticeably better, even on paper.

Comment: I'm a native American English speaker (or at least as close as makes no nevermind), and "took my degree" just sounds utterly wrong to my ears.

Comment: "I got my degree in the University of Somewhere" sounds wrong to my American English-speaking ears too; I have to say "at" or "from" the university.

Comment: British English uses *at* exclusively for the University, and *in* exclusively for the subject. "I took my Degree in Civil Engineering at the University of Surrey."

Answer (score 2):

You took your degree at the University of Life.

You received your degree from the University of Life.

The reason is that you took it — as in studied for it — in the physical location. However the degree was awarded by the institution as an acknowledgement of skills obtained — not necessarily at the same place.

Never "in", at least not in the UK. That is reserved for countries and subjects. So you could say:

> I took my masters degree in English at the University of Life in Belarus, and received my degree from there a year later, after further study abroad.