# Apply to a university to study/for studying..?

Tags: meaning, prepositions, translation

I'm writing my CV and do not know how to correctly say that:
*

> After I graduated from X (//X is a high school), I applied to a
>   university to study chemistry and also computer systems.

*

I'm not sure about the prepositions and also this should be clear that I studied 2 courses (also got 2 degrees). Thank you

Comment: [Apply to vs. apply for](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72490/apply-for-vs-apply-to?rq=1) and [to take a degree in](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46667/take-a-degree-or-do-a-degree) This answer may also be of help: [got a degree vs. took a degree](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49722/did-i-get-or-take-my-degree-from-or-in-the-university-of-somewhere?lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

As far as prepositions go,

I apply/applied/am applying **to** a university **to** study [subjects].

Alternatively, I completed degrees **in** [subjects].

Or even, I am interested in studying **no prepositions** [subjects].

---

Also, as an American reading a CV, when I hear "course" I think of a single class. One term's worth of study.

I would refer to what you're talking about as either a "course of study", or simply a "degree program".

Answer (score 0):

I consider you should be more expansive. "After I graduated from X (//X is a high school), I applied to a university to study chemistry and also computer systems."

Instead, you can use:

"After I graduated from X, I applied to Y College. Chemistry and Computer Systems were my two first options.... " then you can be more expansive and further detail your college experience. Courses finally taken and what degrees you accomplished.

Cheers, Farid.

Comment: Thanks but it does not help with the preposition. I would like to know how to say it with the correct ones (I applied to a university ?? chemistry and computer systems.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a sentence as follows.

> I applied for admission to a University to study chemistry as well as computer systems, after graduating from X (//X is a high school).

In the sentence, **as well as** instead of **and** could express both subjects (chemistry and computer systems) are equally important to you. Using a adverbial clause with adverb particle makes the sentence concise.